# Required XML attribute “adSize” was missing when i have xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" set

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to include ads in my test app, when I run the app in an emulator or a device I get a banner add saying `Required XML attribute “adSize” was missing` .

I have set `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"` in `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` tag.

Not sure how to resolve this issue.

More details :  `Android Studio AI-141.1989493`

Code snippet :

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxxx");
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("E58D5904AA50D88E2FD63A1D1EF97B34")
            .build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01">
<TableRow android:id="@+id/LinearLayout0">


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxxx"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, E58D5904AA50D88E2FD63A1D1EF97B34">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Change:**

xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

**To:**

xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout0"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, E58D5904AA50D88E2FD63A1D1EF97B34">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</TableRow>
```

try this include a property on your root as done here.

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me, and I think it will be all round :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```